# Сохранение класса-структуры максимально сжатым способом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, файлы

Есть класс (структура), пусть такого вида:

```
 class Token {
    public:
        char character;
        unsigned long  dist;
        char length;
 };
```

Его можно записать просто:

```
out->write((char*)(&tmpToken), sizeof(tmpToken));
```

Где:

```
out -> std::ofstream*

tmpToken -> Token
```

3. Также можно записать только его элементы по отдельности...
4. Также есть несколько способов, типа сериализации.
5. Теперь вопрос - как же записать этот класс-структуру так, чтобы она заняла минимум места?

Comment: Завел эту тему, т.к. читал, что есть понятие выравнивания у структур и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Ну можно еще сжать.

Comment: @VTT После упаковки сжать - не то, мне интересно, как изначально записывать максимально сжато

Comment: [__attribute__((packed))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html)

Comment: Видимо самый эффективный по степени сжатия вариант написать функции сериализации/десериализации. И каждая функция бы сохраняла и читала поля по отдельности. Можно даже какие-нибудь оптимизации там примерить, с учетом знания особенностей данного класса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Token {
public:
    unsigned long  dist;
    char character; 
    char length;
};
```

В вашем варианте для каждого поля  выделяется память на одно машинное слово. Чтобы для каждого `char` не выделять память одно машинное слово, эти поля должны идти друг за другом(выделяется одно машинное слово для двух `char`. Все типы(массивы) размером не кратным машинному слову лучше поставить в конец(они должны создаваться последными

Comment: Не понял.......

Comment: что не понятно?  Я ответил на ваш вопрос "как  записать этот класс-структуру так, чтобы она заняла минимум места ". Но не структура занимает место, а ее экземпляры

Comment: Только почему вы вместо "все типы(массивы) размером не кратным машинному слову лучше поставить в конец" в примере ставите dist наверх

Comment: а разве 1 байт делится на 4 или на 8 без остатка?

Comment: На самом деле `sizeof()` у такой  структуры не отличается от структуры в вопросе

Comment: @avp, у вас компилятор слышком умный, и ваша ссылька хорошая

Answer (score 1):

Самое оптимальное по степени сжатия и надёжности - написать функции сериализации/десериализации.
Такой способ

```
out->write((char*)(&tmpToken), sizeof(tmpToken));
```

может привести к проблемам с совместимостью:

- в зависимости от компилятора и настроек компилятора будет разное выравнивание, в результате будет разное расположение полей в памяти и разное значение sizeof(tmpToken)
- теоретически размер char может быть разным на разных платформах. Он может быть 8 бит, а может и 16. Для целей сериализации есть специальные типы: int8_t, uint8_t, int16_t, uint16_t и т.д. Их размер всегда и на всех платформах одинаков.
- размер long int уже гораздо более вероятно может отличаться на разных компиляторах и платформах. Поэтому его точно нужно конвертировать в тип с известным размером.
- могут быть ещё проблемы с Big Endian и Little Endian. Если предполагается кроссплатформенная совместимость сохраняемых файлов или передаваемых данных, то на это тоже надо обратить внимание.

Возможная реализация сериализации:

```
 class Token {
   public:
     char character;
     unsigned long  dist;
     char length;

     void Serialize() {
       out->write(static_cast<uint8_t>(character), sizeof(uint8_t));
       out->write(static_cast<uint32_t>(dist), sizeof(uint32_t));
       out->write(static_cast<uint8_t>(length), sizeof(uint8_t));
     }
 };
```